# How to project a set of points onto an ellipsoid with minimum deformation?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, projective-geometry

I have a set of points that I need to project onto the surface of an ellipsoid (knowing everything about the ellipsoid, also the ellipsoid is centered at the origin).

This is what the ellipsoid and the points look like:

[image] [image]

One possibility I was considering is finding the 2 lines connecting the point with the foci of the ellipse and then computing a point in the line connecting the foci based on a weighted distance (i.e compute a point on the line based on how far away the point is from each foci).

Another option would be to just find the lines connecting the points and the center and project along those lines.

I wanted to know if some one knew of a method to project these points with minimum deformation (i.e try to keep the distance in between the points more or less proportional).

EDIT:

The points here are an exmaple, these needs to work with any set of points "hovering" over the ellipse, regardless of the distance.

Comment: can you consider the possibility to put them centered on the top?

Comment: I do not understand the question

Comment: The most natural approach would be to project them to the nearest point on the ellipsoid. There is no closed form for this, but given that your points all seem to be already very close to the ellipsoid, you can easily compute an approximation by moving along the "approximate normal" of the surface, i.e. the gradient of the quadratic function $Q(x)$ which defines the ellipsoid as $Q(x)=1$.

Comment: I should specify, this is an example, the answer needs to be general enough, so a closed form answer would be ideal, even if it sacrifices a little bit of "deformity".